# Delay in receiving e-mails on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, email

When receiving e-mails on my three PC-s (all with the same e-mail address), on the other two e-mails arrive within 2-3 minutes while on the MacBook Air e-mails come in with a one hour (60 minutes) delay.

Comment: That seems great. If you can figure out how you got your Mac to sit on the mails, please post it. I often want to have them delayed to train people to not email me about urgent things. More importantly, you might want to explain what server settings you have on the Mac and PC to ensure both are accessing the same server over the same protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Check how frequently Mail app is checking for mail - it's adjustable…

[image]

Comment: Possibly a separate question, is there a way (probably with a `defaults` command) to change this value to a specific interval, like 10min.

Comment: @Josh - I'd raise it as a new question. I have no idea, tbh.